# How to display generated latex expression in Matlab live script editor?

Tags: matlab, latex

I'm trying to display a string containing latex expression in which I can insert variables at runtime, using Matlab live script editor.

I need it to be rendered as latex expression and not to be plotted on figure, for example:

```
a = 2.4;
latex_expression = sprintf("$$e^{\\pi i} + %f = 0$$", a);
disp(latex_expression);
```

will output the expression like this:

```
$$e^{\pi i} + 2.400000 = 0$$
```

and I need it to be shown like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the symbolic toolbox:

```
a = 2.4;
syms i
eq = exp(pi*i) + a == 0
```

[image]

The value of `a` will be shown as a fraction though, you can either show everything as floating point using `sympref('FloatingPointOutput', true)`, but this will also show `pi` as floating point.

Comment: symbolic toolbox would be ok if it didn't change the names of constants  to their corresponding numeric values...

Comment: @ZurabKargareteli I am not sure what you mean, but I think it has to do with `syms i`, which you can avoid by doing `symvarname = sym('i')`.

Comment: I mean this:
    `sympref('FloatingPointOutput', true);
    a = 2.4;
    syms i;
    eq = exp(pi*i) + a == 0`

pi becomes 3.14 when I turn on FloatingPointOutput